# SystemC: channels vs port value update

Tags: multithreading, wait, ports, systemc, channel

While working on a SystemC project, I discovered that probably I have some confused ideas about signals and ports. Let's say I have something like this:

```
//cell.hpp

SC_MODULE(Cell)
{ 
   sc_in<sc_uint<16> > datain; 
   sc_in<sc_uint<1> > addr_en;
   sc_in<sc_uint<1> >  enable;
   sc_out<sc_uint<16> > dataout;

   SC_CTOR(Cell)
   {
     SC_THREAD(memory_cell);
        sensitive << enable << datain << addr_en;
   }
   private:
   void memory_cell();
};



//cell.cpp

void Cell::memory_cell()
{  
   unsigned short data_cell=11;

   while(true)
   {     
      //wait for some input
      wait();     

      if (enable->read()==1 && addr_en->read()==1)
      {        
         data_cell=datain->read();        
      }

      else
      {
         if(enable->read()==0 && addr_en->read()==1)
         {
            dataout->write(data_cell);
         }
     }
   }
}





//test.cpp

SC_MODULE(TestBench)
{
   sc_signal<sc_uint<1> > address_en_s;
   sc_signal<sc_uint<16> > datain_s;  
   sc_signal<sc_uint<1> >  enable_s;
   sc_signal<sc_uint<16> > dataout_s;   

   Cell cella;

   SC_CTOR(TestBench) : cella("cella")
   {
        // Binding
        cella.addr_en(address_en_s);
        cella.datain(datain_s);
        cella.enable(enable_s);
        cella.dataout(dataout_s);               
        SC_THREAD(stimulus_thread);                        
   }


  private:
    void stimulus_thread() {  

//write a value:    
        datain_s.write(81);    
        address_en_s.write(1);    
        enable_s.write(1);         
        wait(SC_ZERO_TIME);


//read what we have written:
        enable_s.write(0);
        address_en_s.write(1);
        wait(SC_ZERO_TIME);

        cout << "Output value: " << dataout_s.read() << endl;


//let's cycle the memory again:       
        address_en_s.write(0);         
        wait(SC_ZERO_TIME);
        cout << "Output value: " << dataout_s.read() << endl;

    }   
};
```

I've tried running this modules and I've noticed something weird (at least, weird for me): when the stimulus writes a value (81), after the `wait(SC_ZERO_TIME)` the memory thread finds its `datain`, `enable` and `address_enable` values already updated. This is what I expected to happen. The same happens when the stimulus changes the `enable_es` value, in order to run another cycle in the memory thread and copy the `data_cell` value into the memory cell `dataout` port. What I don't understand is why after the memory module writes into its `dataout` port and goes again to the `wait()` statement at the beginning of the while loop, the stimulus module still has the old value on its `dataout_s` channel (0), and not the new value(81), which has just been copied by the memory module. Then, if I run another cycle of the memory loop (for example changing some values on the stimulus channels), the dataout channel finnally updates.

In other words, it looks like that if I write into the stimulus channels and then switch to the memory thread, the memory finds the values updated. But if the memory thread writes into its ports, and then I switch to the stimulus thread, the thread still sees the old values on its channels (binded to the memory ports).

Answer (score 0):

The example above is not working as I expected because of a wrong delta cycle synchronization.

Generally speaking, lets suppose we have two threads running on two modules, A and B, connected through a channel. If I write something in threadA during delta cycle number 1, it will only be available in thread B during delta cycle 2. And if thread B writes something during its delta cycle 2, thread A has to wait until delta cycle 3 in order to read it.

Being aware of this, stimulus thread would need two consecutive `wait(SC_ZERO_TIME)` statements in order to read the correct output from the memory, because it has to forward its delta value.